# Bitcoin core sync stuck with an error "peer=X is stalling block download"

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet, stale-block

I have installed bitcoin core (23.0) on a virtual machine (Debian GNU/Linux 10, x86_64) and tried to start the testnet initial block download. Unfortunately,a few days ago blockchain sync is stuck on a particular block 4032 and constantly reports following lines

```
2022-08-03T18:58:26Z Synchronizing blockheaders, height: 2262031 (~99.69%)
2022-08-03T18:58:26Z Peer=6 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2022-08-03T18:58:26Z Synchronizing blockheaders, height: 2264031 (~99.69%)
2022-08-03T18:58:32Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=2314713, peer=16 (outbound-full-relay)
```

This problem is not present on mainnet and my `bitcoin.conf` currently looks simply this way

```
testnet=1
prune=550
```

What I've already tried:

1. Run `bitcoind` with `-maxconnections=1`
2. Run `bitcoind` with `-reindex`
3. Tried different configurations of `bitcoin.conf`
4. Delete `.bitcoin` data directory and restart `bitcoind`
5. `invalidate block`

all steps were unsuccessful :'(

[image: Stuck on this]

I am ready to provide further information and would appreciate if someone could help with this issue! Also, I am quite a newbie, so I could be missing something obvious.

With `listen=0` and after removing datadir `testnet3`:

```
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z   - Connect postprocess: 0.88ms [3.43s (0.85ms/blk)]
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z - Connect block: 1.65ms [6.09s (1.51ms/blk)]
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z Enqueuing BlockConnected: block hash=000000001af3b22a7598b10574deb6b3e2d596f36d62b0a49cb89a1f99ab81eb block height=4032
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z Enqueuing UpdatedBlockTip: new block hash=000000001af3b22a7598b10574deb6b3e2d596f36d62b0a49cb89a1f99ab81eb fork block hash=000000002e9ccffc999166ccf8d72129e1b2e9c754f6c90ad2f77cab0d9fb4c7 (in IBD=true)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z Requesting block 0000000001b8c862bc9d5bcb0b15695bef9eafaf31d39678d08f8cbbba6f041b (4096) peer=0
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getdata (37 bytes) peer=0
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z UpdatedBlockTip: new block hash=000000004b072849e63b49f209cf966847569e9ae5aa0a5e83e7847c143168b0 fork block hash=000000009577b19248f3c4bebddb6b6ca2105e1f700b63a045057f74fee18687 (in IBD=true)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z BlockConnected: block hash=000000002e9ccffc999166ccf8d72129e1b2e9c754f6c90ad2f77cab0d9fb4c7 block height=4031
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z UpdatedBlockTip: new block hash=000000002e9ccffc999166ccf8d72129e1b2e9c754f6c90ad2f77cab0d9fb4c7 fork block hash=000000004b072849e63b49f209cf966847569e9ae5aa0a5e83e7847c143168b0 (in IBD=true)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z BlockConnected: block hash=000000001af3b22a7598b10574deb6b3e2d596f36d62b0a49cb89a1f99ab81eb block height=4032
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z UpdatedBlockTip: new block hash=000000001af3b22a7598b10574deb6b3e2d596f36d62b0a49cb89a1f99ab81eb fork block hash=000000002e9ccffc999166ccf8d72129e1b2e9c754f6c90ad2f77cab0d9fb4c7 (in IBD=true)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=2
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (2061999) to end to peer=2 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=2
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=3
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (2057999) to end to peer=3 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=3
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1975999) to end to peer=8 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1979999) to end to peer=1 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=6
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1693999) to end to peer=6 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=6
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1837999) to end to peer=4 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1981999) to end to peer=1 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1839999) to end to peer=4 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=2
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (2063999) to end to peer=2 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=2
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=3
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (2059999) to end to peer=3 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=3
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1977999) to end to peer=8 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1841999) to end to peer=4 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1983999) to end to peer=1 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1979999) to end to peer=8 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1843999) to end to peer=4 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=3
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (2061999) to end to peer=3 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=3
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=2
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (2065999) to end to peer=2 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=2
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1985999) to end to peer=1 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1845999) to end to peer=4 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=6
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1695999) to end to peer=6 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=6
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1981999) to end to peer=8 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=8
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1987999) to end to peer=1 (startheight:2315040)
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z sending getheaders (1061 bytes) peer=1
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z received: headers (162003 bytes) peer=4
2022-08-05T17:33:57Z more getheaders (1847999) to end to peer=4 (startheight:2315040)
```

... and ...

```
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 172.76.167.210:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[118][47]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 44.234.48.207:3000 mapped to AS0 to new[377][51]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 95.217.106.33:16666 mapped to AS0 to new[764][36]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 102.91.5.163:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[53][32]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 18.237.199.30:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[893][12]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 45.90.211.106:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[632][36]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 89.145.164.141:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[380][12]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 181.90.78.167:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[202][8]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 35.176.160.196:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[410][35]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 147.182.228.171:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[964][4]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 195.206.2.235:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[242][42]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2001:861:3dc3:2670:b8d9:59c5:e41a:4e7d]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[1000][54]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 185.220.101.156:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[729][5]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 3.212.1.199:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[959][51]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 94.231.253.18:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[722][26]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 192.145.119.170:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[775][17]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 46.158.72.210:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[190][58]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 163.172.140.222:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[689][17]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 5.14.213.154:18445 from new[242][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 46.243.25.106:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[242][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 196.178.74.11:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[309][18]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 91.225.142.178:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[722][33]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 13.215.108.60:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[53][15]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 54.64.59.249:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[53][48]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 174.127.250.4:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[764][13]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 154.204.24.234:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[116][33]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2a01:5ec0:1802:3354:799e:13dd:45a:b738]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[71][21]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 45.32.110.61:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[729][51]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 192.46.234.64:18333 from new[932][36]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 92.115.99.159:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[932][36]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed [2404:7a80:30e0:3800:70e6:98b5:da5:10fa]:18333 from new[775][14]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 101.224.16.240:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[775][14]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 187.109.87.182:18333 from new[544][30]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 198.8.92.88:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[544][30]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 189.147.148.39:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[323][54]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 176.232.63.113:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[616][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 172.105.84.158:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[334][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2a01:4f8:151:30c9::2]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[435][38]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 103.55.11.35:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[53][39]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 54.215.35.252:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[309][41]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 3.73.44.141:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[306][43]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2a02:a210:2041:34f0:31f6:deaa:7d6b:d08]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[616][46]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 131.94.186.110:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[118][13]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 80.49.50.192:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[245][35]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 142.147.89.228:18333 from new[377][39]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 34.105.113.80:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[377][39]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 195.154.200.157:8333 mapped to AS0 to new[435][39]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 18.237.26.158:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[893][56]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 88.118.15.170:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[964][49]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2a01:4f8:10b:a85::2]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[435][54]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 41.147.0.51:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[53][53]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 3.121.218.237:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[190][15]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 161.97.146.5:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[466][59]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 180.123.22.114:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[995][11]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 93.173.235.84:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[662][34]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 176.63.24.73:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[380][44]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 45.20.115.208:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[765][29]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 31.61.238.243:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[334][44]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 34.139.188.226:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[1002][40]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 54.169.102.36:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[153][1]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 45.33.48.32:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[806][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 178.239.173.192:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[410][24]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 194.105.137.123:18333 from new[997][40]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 63.248.86.232:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[997][40]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 197.210.71.117:18333 from new[194][50]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 85.221.228.98:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[194][50]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 95.102.215.12:8333 from new[205][45]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2001:0:9d38:6abd:242e:1556:b98f:a440]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[205][45]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 52.56.40.174:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[921][38]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 118.78.39.4:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[729][61]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2405:6583:9300:6f00:411f:4bc1:a3ba:c44e]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[53][41]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 177.39.33.46:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[242][46]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 47.75.136.114:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[197][42]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 18.208.195.121:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[944][58]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 3.235.199.140:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[1000][44]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 45.76.27.11:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[334][54]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 59.40.141.29:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[209][53]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2603:7080:ec40:1b00::17dd]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[886][32]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 62.23.155.50:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[678][28]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 203.189.252.172:20020 mapped to AS0 to new[1002][0]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 52.3.226.5:30000 mapped to AS0 to new[190][12]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 219.152.31.241:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[944][9]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed [2a0e:1d40:805:3700:85d9:ab91:63f9:61ba]:18333 from new[306][38]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2601:647:5680:5440:dbb:af47:d5c3:c913]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[306][38]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 3.20.168.21:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[118][39]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 54.198.73.12:18333 from new[765][53]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2a01:4ff:f0:4456::1]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[765][53]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 20.76.160.107:39388 mapped to AS0 to new[194][26]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 114.255.110.130:39388 mapped to AS0 to new[678][58]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 50.2.13.165:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[202][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 181.45.24.195:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[194][12]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 81.148.223.188:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[431][8]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 31.22.203.42:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[921][59]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 185.220.101.182:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[729][48]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 172.76.174.137:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[118][35]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Removed 161.97.88.150:18333 from new[466][26]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 142.132.252.156:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[466][26]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 40.91.196.213:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[205][54]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added [2601:646:9c00:a9d0:b5d0:28f1:ec9e:c7c9]:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[194][57]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 207.244.177.107:18333 mapped to AS0 to new[334][14]
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z Added 494 addresses (of 881) from 3.18.26.129: 30 tried, 8326 new
2022-08-05T17:51:25Z received: pong (8 bytes) peer=39
2022-08-05T17:51:26Z Selected 34.207.108.183:18333 from tried
2022-08-05T17:51:26Z Selected 91.214.220.136:18333 from new
2022-08-05T17:51:26Z Selected 34.207.108.183:18333 from tried
2022-08-05T17:51:27Z Selected [2603:6080:6a03:c300:c104:8a1d:5a25:e7c6]:18333 from new
2022-08-05T17:51:27Z trying connection [2603:6080:6a03:c300:c104:8a1d:5a25:e7c6]:18333 lastseen=331.5hrs
```

... and ...

```
2022-08-05T18:13:09Z connection attempt to 217.138.199.93:18333 timed out
2022-08-05T18:13:10Z Selected 35.78.193.194:18333 from new
2022-08-05T18:13:10Z trying connection 35.78.193.194:18333 lastseen=286.2hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:10Z sending ping (8 bytes) peer=114
2022-08-05T18:13:15Z connection attempt to 35.78.193.194:18333 timed out
2022-08-05T18:13:15Z Selected 51.77.119.85:18333 from tried
2022-08-05T18:13:15Z Selected 172.81.180.110:18333 from new
2022-08-05T18:13:15Z trying connection 172.81.180.110:18333 lastseen=10.7hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:20Z connection attempt to 172.81.180.110:18333 timed out
2022-08-05T18:13:21Z Selected 80.133.96.162:18333 from new
2022-08-05T18:13:21Z trying connection 80.133.96.162:18333 lastseen=644.4hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:22Z sending ping (8 bytes) peer=115
2022-08-05T18:13:23Z sending ping (8 bytes) peer=116
2022-08-05T18:13:26Z connection attempt to 80.133.96.162:18333 timed out
2022-08-05T18:13:26Z Selected 52.0.54.100:18333 from tried
2022-08-05T18:13:26Z trying connection 52.0.54.100:18333 lastseen=0.5hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:26Z Added connection peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:26Z sending version (102 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:26Z send version message: version 70016, blocks=4032, txrelay=1, peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: version (102 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending wtxidrelay (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendaddrv2 (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending verack (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending getaddr (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z receive version message: /Satoshi:0.21.0/: version 70016, blocks=2315045, us=130.149.221.147:59312, txrelay=1, peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: wtxidrelay (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendaddrv2 (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: verack (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=2315045, peer=128 (outbound-full-relay)
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendheaders (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending ping (8 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z initial getheaders (2315044) to peer=128 (startheight:2315045)
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending getheaders (1093 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending feefilter (8 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendheaders (0 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: ping (8 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending pong (8 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: addrv2 (16 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Received addr: 1 addresses (1 processed, 0 rate-limited) from peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: getheaders (1093 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Ignoring getheaders from peer=128 because node is in initial block download
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: feefilter (8 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: feefilter of 0.00001000 BTC/kvB from peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: pong (8 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: headers (82 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Protecting outbound peer=128 from eviction
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Stall started peer=127
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Selected 94.23.33.130:18333 from tried
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z trying connection 94.23.33.130:18333 lastseen=0.2hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Added connection peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending version (102 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z send version message: version 70016, blocks=4032, txrelay=0, peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: version (103 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending wtxidrelay (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendaddrv2 (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending verack (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z receive version message: /Satoshi:21.99.0/: version 70016, blocks=2315045, us=130.149.221.147:46822, txrelay=1, peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: wtxidrelay (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendaddrv2 (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: verack (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=2315045, peer=129 (block-relay-only)
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendheaders (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending ping (8 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z initial getheaders (2315044) to peer=129 (startheight:2315045)
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending getheaders (1093 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendheaders (0 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: sendcmpct (9 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: ping (8 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z sending pong (8 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: addrv2 (16 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z ignoring addrv2 message from block-relay-only peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: getheaders (1093 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z Ignoring getheaders from peer=129 because node is in initial block download
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: feefilter (8 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: feefilter of 0.00001000 BTC/kvB from peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: pong (8 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:27Z received: headers (82 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:28Z Selected 201.213.139.40:18333 from new
2022-08-05T18:13:28Z Making feeler connection to 201.213.139.40:18333
2022-08-05T18:13:28Z trying connection 201.213.139.40:18333 lastseen=39.8hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Peer=127 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z disconnecting peer=127
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Cleared nodestate for peer=127
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000db623a1752143f2f805c4527573570d9b4ca0a3cfe371e703ac429aa (4033) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 0000000073d8b2f92be7a94ee567f07fb0bead01364a68afe11e1fe2a03f9448 (4036) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000ff0106750519cd7b545f639e9bae958183792c5f34e95e1a490630d1 (4041) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000cee0b413b827d1f0ced850d8b69cf591b8304b49e7ca263e3aea0f38 (4045) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 0000000037352c5bef9447da95603add1bb14bac64619894a50d78ff7c394cd1 (4047) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000581a124da37e9c16ea43e0725962a31f68430be749e21bd1902101b8 (4053) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000691dadb3705b7b8a0902bcf893292b454b809e12924a71e20c341a41 (4057) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 000000004e7c05621db9cdcf62d362efb914721c4094dc8b8c6677db56c3d489 (4064) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000988a45071d7cf0a9aa61ba1ede22df9dce2ffe5e79607f4d7e936a40 (4065) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000678ffa59dd961b372173196f0713eb36f7ec8a3324d78cfcb19c7c7a (4070) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 0000000030beedda39a27dd825f0ee83ba06f537be9a3dd621ba0baa2fc91b82 (4073) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 000000007a78cdc2bb51b2058bb20f1921250abbbf564d16511b805428d56054 (4079) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 0000000067570ed3aed985b70372b3e7be7dfb265d348b803977a40774ca057c (4080) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 000000006464a1f36a0a4076a193913b5f24b9bb435925f111c23c66c975615d (4086) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 00000000ce8084c04d41ea5b1650424414ebb6a2e9544be32d79923bab7a5eef (4087) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Requesting block 000000005225db12742b41070a0239c708cae1cfee79caa65560cb8a4ee2d090 (4091) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z sending getdata (577 bytes) peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:29Z Stall started peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Peer=129 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z disconnecting peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Cleared nodestate for peer=129
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000db623a1752143f2f805c4527573570d9b4ca0a3cfe371e703ac429aa (4033) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 0000000073d8b2f92be7a94ee567f07fb0bead01364a68afe11e1fe2a03f9448 (4036) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000ff0106750519cd7b545f639e9bae958183792c5f34e95e1a490630d1 (4041) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000cee0b413b827d1f0ced850d8b69cf591b8304b49e7ca263e3aea0f38 (4045) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 0000000037352c5bef9447da95603add1bb14bac64619894a50d78ff7c394cd1 (4047) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000581a124da37e9c16ea43e0725962a31f68430be749e21bd1902101b8 (4053) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000691dadb3705b7b8a0902bcf893292b454b809e12924a71e20c341a41 (4057) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 000000004e7c05621db9cdcf62d362efb914721c4094dc8b8c6677db56c3d489 (4064) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000988a45071d7cf0a9aa61ba1ede22df9dce2ffe5e79607f4d7e936a40 (4065) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000678ffa59dd961b372173196f0713eb36f7ec8a3324d78cfcb19c7c7a (4070) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 0000000030beedda39a27dd825f0ee83ba06f537be9a3dd621ba0baa2fc91b82 (4073) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 000000007a78cdc2bb51b2058bb20f1921250abbbf564d16511b805428d56054 (4079) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 0000000067570ed3aed985b70372b3e7be7dfb265d348b803977a40774ca057c (4080) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 000000006464a1f36a0a4076a193913b5f24b9bb435925f111c23c66c975615d (4086) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 00000000ce8084c04d41ea5b1650424414ebb6a2e9544be32d79923bab7a5eef (4087) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z Requesting block 000000005225db12742b41070a0239c708cae1cfee79caa65560cb8a4ee2d090 (4091) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:31Z sending getdata (577 bytes) peer=128
2022-08-05T18:13:33Z connection attempt to 201.213.139.40:18333 timed out
2022-08-05T18:13:34Z Selected 107.189.31.134:18333 from new
2022-08-05T18:13:34Z trying connection 107.189.31.134:18333 lastseen=114.7hrs
2022-08-05T18:13:35Z received: headers (82 bytes) peer=122
2022-08-05T18:13:35Z Stall started peer=128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's helpful comments, but I have had no luck solving this problem in a "clean" way. Since I tried to run the nodes on the university's virtual machines, I suspect the problem could be related to networking (firewall or router settings). Also important to note is that on the mainnet the initial block download went smoothly (explanation is possible [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/11037#issuecomment-322064477)).

So my hotfix was to run the test nodes via Tor.  With this set-up, the initial block download continued and succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this, I can sync fine on testnet beyond this point.

Did you delete the correct datadir (.bitcoin/testnet3) in step 4? And did it then start syncing headers from 0% (you can check debug.log in the datadir folder) and get stuck at the same point again?

What does `bitcoin-cli -testnet getchaintips` say when you are stuck?

Comment: Yes, I removed .bitcoin/testnet3, and then the sync stuck on the exact same block again. I even reimaged the virtual machine, but that didn't help either. The download has stopped at the same point again, and I'm getting these stall messages.

Comment: If you run with `-debug`, do you get more relevant messages in debug.log?

Comment: I noticed from your screenshot that you have 1 inbound peer, which may be doing something weird. Maybe you could check if deleting the datadir and temporarily disabling inbound peers (listen=0 in your bitcoin.conf) changes anything?

Comment: Stuck again at 4032

Comment: Can you see in the logs (with -debug enabled) if you get block 4033 ("00000000db623a1752143f2f805c4527573570d9b4ca0a3cfe371e703ac429aa") but fail to validate it for some reason? Otherwise, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: I am requesting it but apparently, I don't get it. Sorry for the dumb question but how can I check it?

Comment: I got version, verack, sendheaders, sendcmpct, addr, feefilter.

Comment: As far I understand, then the stalling begins and the same behavior happens with the other peers

Comment: I wonder if maybe there is a problem with the firewall. I am running bitcoin core on the university VM's